# Render react component on node server, with webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sass, isomorphic-javascript

I have a react component. `<myFooter>`. It is a simple footer.

```
import React from 'react';
import './my-footer.scss';

export default class myFooter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <footer className="col-xs-12">
      hello !
    </footer>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to render it from the server-side. On the backend, I have an express server. For that I wrote this:

```
import myFooter from '../components/my-footer.jsx';

app.get('/footer', function(req, res) {
  var string1 = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(myFooter);
  res.send(string1);
});
```

Now the problem is that server cannot read sass files. For client side rendering, I am using webpack. Webpack builds everything and gives a bundle file.

But i'm not sure what happens if its the server side. How can I compile using webpack. If I can, will i need to compile my app for each request on node server ?

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 webpack builds:

1 to build the client
1 to build the server.

When building the server, use `css-loader/locals` instead of `css-loader` in your webpack configuration.

Read through this issue for more details: https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/59